# Return in which table the item was found

Tags: php, laravel

In this code I return subcategory or category object containing id, title which was found. But how to return also information where this item was found in Subcategory or Category?
My controller code:

```
if($search_type=='category'){
$resault=Category::where('title','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->get();
$resault=Subcategory::where('title','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->get();
}
return $resault;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to merge these both results and return finally as

```
$finalResult=[];
if($search_type=='category'){
    $catResult=json_decode(json_encode(Category::where('title','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->get()));
    $subCatresult=json_decode(json_encode(Subcategory::where('title','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->get()));
    $finalResult=array_merge($catResult,$subCatResult);
}
return $finalResult;
```

Comment: I thought about sth easier like: `            $resault=Category::where('title','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->put('kind', 'category')->get();
`
But I get an error: `Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::put does not exist.`